# Is it possible to create a BrowserSession for Direct TCP transport?

Tags: browser, blackberry, transport

My BlackBerry app opens BB Browser to display a web page for users.

There is BlackBerry KB doc ["How to - Invoke the browser"](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800440/How_To_-_Invoke_the_browser.html?nodeid=1487366&vernum=0) on how to do it.

The doc says there are the following types of transports to choose:

```
public static final int SERVICE_RECORD_CONFIG_TYPE_WAP  = 0;
public static final int SERVICE_RECORD_CONFIG_TYPE_BES  = 1;
public static final int SERVICE_RECORD_CONFIG_TYPE_WIFI = 3;
public static final int SERVICE_RECORD_CONFIG_TYPE_BIS  = 4;
public static final int SERVICE_RECORD_CONFIG_TYPE_WAP2 = 7;
```

My question is how can I use Direct TCP. Probably there is some SERVICE_RECORD_CONFIG_**DIRECT_TCP** value?

P.S.

If I simply get the default BrowserSession by `Browser.getDefaultSession()`, it uses BES/MDS transport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Browser transport can only use service records of the "BrowserConfig" type.  I doubt there is a BrowserConfig service record for Direct TCP - I don't think I've seen the capability in any BlackBerry I've worked with.  You can take a look at all the BrowserConfig service records on your device, but I doubt you'll find one for the Direct TCP transport.

From the comments in the code provided by the link you referenced:

> There are 5 different browing models available: WAP, BlackBerry Internet Service (BIS), BlackBerry Enterprise Server (BES), WiFi, BlackBerry Unite!

Comment: UPDATE: MSohm from BB support forum confirmed Direct TCP is not supported.